# javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder generate java.util.Date as number

Tags: java, rest

I'm using javaee-api 6.0.

I have an entity bean with a java.util.Date field called updated.

```
public class Tariff implements Serializable {
    private Date updated
```

And I have a REST service.

```
@GET
@Path("/example")
public Response getTariff() {
    return Response.status(200).entity(new Records(createExampleTariff())).build();
}
```

When I call my REST service it returns the date as a number.

```
{"records":{"description":"OTHER","message":"Nothing to say","status":"OK", "updated":1475822878961},"status":"ok"}
```

Anyone know how I can work past this, without using a DTO.

Comment: the date is always stored as the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.

Comment: Hi jp, do you really need to return the date in human readable form? Long dates are easier to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason:**

`The date is always stored as the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.`

**Solution:**

You can convert the Date format using `org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonSerializer`. by writing a class JsonDateSerializer with that conversion logic.

```
@JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)
public Date getDate() {
   return date;
}
```

you can get detailed explanation [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-serialize-javautildate)

Comment: The reading works fine now, but when I try to post and update it tells me: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2016-10-07 09:16:51': not a valid representation (error: Can not parse date "2016-10-07 09:16:51": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))

Comment: In conversion you can write logic to create a date in any of asked format. e.g. "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: in JsonDateSerializer  instead of using "MM-dd-yyyy" dateformat use any of the specified

Comment: I switched to one of the asked formats and all is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

The Date class is in fact the wrapper for a number, the number being the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.
You need to specify what you mean by "work past this".  Either you send a number or a string.  For a string, you can use SimpleDateFormat to produce the string you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would still go with returing the timestamp so it remains simple. If you really need to send the date in human readable format you can create a class that extends org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonSerializer and implement the serialize method as you want. Then   anotate the date getter like this

```
@JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)
public Date getDate() {
   return date;
}
```

Check [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-serialize-javautildate) for more info